React Native error: Unimplemented component <RNCSafeAreaProvider>
I am new to React Native so bear with me but does anyone know how to resolve this error? For some reason when I run my app on an older simulator it does not give me the error (image attached) but when I run it on a newer simulator it does. Thanks for the help!


Did you resolve that ?

Thanks for the comment. I was able to fix my issue by downgrading to the previous version of React Native. Not ideal but helps with testing in the meantime. –

Yes I also resolved with downgrade and that's work, thats reason I ping you , so I will help you

Not a long term fix but for me downgrading to these versions, fixed the issue for me.

"react-native-screens": "3.35.0",
"@react-navigation/native": "6.1.18",
"@react-navigation/native-stack": "6.11.0",


Thanks for the comment.. I tried downgrading those dependencies but it did not work.

Try wrapping your component in a SafeAreaProvider tag
import { SafeAreaProvider } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';

export default App = () => {

  return (
    <SafeAreaProvider>
      <MainNavigation />
    </SafeAreaProvider>
  );
}


Thanks for the suggestion; I will try this. I was able to fix my issue by downgrading to the previous version of React Native. Not ideal but helps with testing in the meantime.
